# How to read data written by google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream::WriteVarint32ToArray

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I'm using this method in `google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream` to write variable length encoded integers to a buffer:

```
static uint8 * WriteVarint32ToArray(uint32 value, uint8 * target)
```

What is the corresponding method to read the same value?

I see these in the documentation:

```
static const uint8 * ReadLittleEndian32FromArray(const uint8 * buffer, uint32 * value)
static const uint8 * ReadLittleEndian64FromArray(const uint8 * buffer, uint64 * value)
```

But none that seems to do what I need. I was expecting a `ReadVarint32FromArray` but this seems unavailable. Since I read an write a memory buffer and not a stream, i need a static method like the one uesd for writing.

The documentation: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.io.coded_stream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CodedInputStream::ReadVarint32`. There's no `static` version, you would need to actually instantiate a `CodedInputStream` backed by your array; there's a constructor taking pointer and size.